# how to validate jsp password fields using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jsp, struts2-jquery

I would like to check (into a jsp page) whether the values of password1 & password2 are equal or not. And if they are not equal, it will stay on the same page. Otherwise it will update. I could do all things but I am unable to make the form to stay on the same page if the passwords are not equal. the codes which i tried are like the following:

- here, action is a struts2 action which is defined into struts.xml file

### Form code:

```
<form id="form1" method="post"  action="saveUpdatePassword">
    Password:         <s:password name="password1" id="password1" />
    Re-type password: <s:password name="password2" id="password2" />
                      <input type="submit" id="sumbitButton" value="Update" />
</form>
```

### and the jQuery script code:

```
$(function() {
    $("#sumbitButton").click(function() {
        if ($("#password1").val() != $("#password2").val()) {
            alert("Not equal");
        }           
    });
});
```

Can you tell me how to make the form staying on the same page if the password does not match? And provide users to put the password again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `event.preventDefault()`

```
$(function() {
    $("#sumbitButton").click(function(event) {
        if ($("#password1").val() != $("#password2").val()) {
            alert("Not equal");
            event.preventDefault();
        }           
    });
});
```

Note the `event` parameter being passed into the click handler.

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Comment: if i use event.preventDefault(), then it shows the password is changed. But when i check into database, i am seeing that the password is not changed.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by 'it shows the password is changed'.  Where/what are you looking at?

Comment: i added an else block like "else{  alert("Password has been updated successfully.");  }" with the above code. So, when the password maches it shows that the password update succesfully. but the password is not updated when i am checking into the database.

Comment: Ok, I understand now. I don't think we can help with that given the code you've posted.  Since it sounds like you've found a solution to the original question (how to prevent the form from submitting), you should accept an answer and then open a new question for your latest problem.

Answer (score 0):

If result is false then simply return false, which will prevent the form to post.

```
$(function() {
        $("#sumbitButton").click(function() {
            if ($("#password1").val() != $("#password2").val()) {
                alert("Not equal");
                return false;
            }           
        });
    });
```

**EDIT**: When password changed successfully

```
var wnd = window.open(blah,blah,blah . . . . .)
```

you can close the window as `wnd.close();`

Comment: Yes, it's working. I do this using a popup window. And after chaning the password the window is still opened. Is it possible to automatically close the window after updating the password.

Comment: Returning `false` works, but `event.preventDefault()` is (probably) the better solution.  See http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/

Comment: i am useing code like window.open(url,'1386696505984','width=600,height=400,toolbar=0,menubar=0,locati‌​on=0,status=1,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,left=0,top=0'); to create the jsp page which pops up a new window and then provides the option to change the password. And i want to close the window if password is changed successfully.